# Project reference dll --> FileLoadException

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, project-reference, fileloadexception, dll-reference

I'm having a problem with project references in .Net
I have three projects:
Console Application 
MVC 3 Web Application
Class library (Mails)

Both console and web apps reference the Mails project.
Mails project references RazorEngine.dll.

Now, when I run the console app everything goes fine, it uses Mails with no errors.
When I run the web app and it attempts to use Mails, it throws FileLoadException.

I can't figure out why is this happening, because both apps use the same piece of code in the Mails project.

RazorEngine.dll is in the bin folder of my web app so I don't know why it isn't found.

Please help!!! I need to solve this at work :S

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's either a Permissions issue or a dependency issue. If it works fine as a console app, you've probably satisfied all of the dependencies, so it's almost certainly a permissions problem. If you haven't already, see if more information is provided in the event log (you should see an error log for the exception.)

Depending on your version of IIS, you may need to add either IUSR_[MACHINENAME] or IIS_IUSRS to have read permission on everything that your app needs (including the bin folder, and each thing in it.)

Comment: I agree it's probably a permissions issue. I am running the application in the ASP.NET Development Server, can that cause any problem? I have IIS 7.5 but I'm not publishing my app there.